# Check if inner lists contain some string value in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have searched a lot. But couldn't get what I am looking for.

I have a list with inner lists as its objects

```
final posts = [ ["My First Post, "myPostId"], ["My SecondPost, "myPostId2"]..... ];
```

So, I want to check if the list contains the word `First`.
It is working with 1D lists like

```
posts = ["My First Post", "My Second Post"];
posts.where((p)=>p.contain("First")....

//gives the correct result
```

But what's the way to get from the inner lists.

Actual Code

```
final suggestion = query.isEmpty?courseNameList:courseNameList
.where((test)=>test.contains(query.toLowerCase())).toList();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can create a other one dimension list and search from it and then base on index display data whatever you want to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello check this solution if it is ok:

```
final posts = [ 
  ["My First Post", "myPostId"], 
  ["My SecondPost", "myPostId2"],
];

void main() {
  List suggestions = List();
  posts.forEach((postList){
    if(postList[0].contains("First")) 
      suggestions.add(postList);

  });

  suggestions.forEach((sugg)=>print("Found ID: ${sugg[1]}"));
}
```

Comment: ```final suggestion = query.isEmpty?courseNameList:courseNameListLower
.where((test)=>test.contains(query.toLowerCase())).toList();
```
This is my actual code. I need to assign those results into list (suggestion), instead .

Comment: @FathahKodag I have modified my answer to return a List; hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {
  final result = posts.any((e) => e.any((e) => e.contains('First')));
  print(result);
}

final posts = [
  ["My First Post", "myPostId"],
  ["My SecondPost", "myPostId2"]
];
```

Comment: I need to assign those results to another list.
As ```any()``` is a bool I cannot get the result, instead, it returns true/false

Comment: Please check the question. I  have added some more code.

Comment: This was the answer to your main question `Check if inner lists contain some string value in Flutter`. Documentation: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-core/Iterable/any.html  `Checks whether any element of this iterable satisfies test.`. What exactly does not suit you?

Comment: Ask a new question on StackOverflow. `what's the way to get from the inner lists`.

Comment: Tnx for trying.